# Android - Setting up Roboguice 2.0?

Tags: android, guice, roboguice

I started a new project (In Eclipse classic), added `roboguice-2.0.jar` `guice-2.0-no-aop.jar` and `jsr305-1.3.9.jar` to my project and my build path.

The first step is to extend RoboApplication, but eclipse cannot find the matching package for this class. I looked at the source and the package for roboguice is `roboguice.application.RoboApplication` which does not exist.
There is no application under roboguice in my project.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So, frustratingly, the roboguice library development has [outpaced its documentation](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/roboguice/fE7-TUGioJo). There is no RoboApplication class in the new libary.

Instead you should remove that file and create a roboguice.xml file in your values that points to your custom robo module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources> 
    <string-array name="roboguice_modules">
    <item>com.mypackage.MyModule</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

Also if you were using AbstractAndroidModule or RoboModule for your module code it is now called AbstractModule.

Comment: The latest version for Android would be the no_aop jar from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Guice40)? The RoboGuice jar is needed anymore? Please update the answer, it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using RoboGuice 2 you should be using Guice 3 and not Guice 2!!! There is quite a bit of documentation available on the wiki. Specifically check out

http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/InstallationNonMaven

http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/UpgradingTo20